# Generalizing a User Interface of an application

Tags: c++, c, linux, automatic-generalization

I am working in C language and creating applications for an embedded device. These applications mainly
include capturing data and storing it into a database for performing an enrollment. This involves lot of 
widgets like frames, buttons, check-boxes, radio buttons, widget list boxes, text boxes, entries, combo boxes etc. All these widgets are being created using the X library.

I have tried to make the application generalized using CSV files, having a list of all the widgets that the user wants to create and then creating those widgets accordingly based on the information mentioned 
in the CSV file.

The CSV file that I am creating includes things like

1. Widget name
2. Widget type
3. Widget data input type/max length / min length 
   .....
   ..... etc.

Please suggest some other ways or how can I improve the current way itself?
I am also creating the DB by the information provided in the CSV itself. I can say that it's 
a "Data Driven User Interface" approach. I need some suggestions. Please provide me 
some good suggestions.

Platform: Linux, GCC compiler

Comment: What's your complaint with the way you're doing it now?

Comment: Iam trying to find some way that is more efficient that this.

Comment: I believe this is referred to as a "Data Driven User Interface". How do you specify the callback function for each widget?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not quite what you are looking for but WxWidgets has a format called XRC. It's windows described as XML: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.4/overview_xrc.html. Are you really writing your GUI in C? I guess that might be a constraint on an embedded product.
Anyway, you might get good ideas from the site. I haven't used it so no specific feedback is available from me.